# como hago para tomar el id de un tag y luego sea guardado en un variable de javascript

Tags: php, javascript

```
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
<?php
$user="localhost";
$username="root";
$pass="";
$db="despensa";
$conexion=mysqli_connect($user,$username,$pass,$db)or die  ("ERROR DE CONEXION");
                            $consultar="select * from cliente ";
                            $resultado=$conexion->query($consultar);
                            while ($resultados=$resultado->fetch_assoc()){
                                ?>

                                <?php $a=$resultados['email'];?> 
                                <?php $b=$resultados['idcliente'];?> 
                        <ul>
                                <li><a id="<?php echo $a?>" href="#" onclick="name();"><?php echo $a?></a></li>


                                </ul>

                                <script type="text/javascript">
                                function name() {
                                    var name = document.getElementById("<?php echo $a?>").value;
                                    alert(name);
                                }
                                </script>           
                    <?php }?>



</body>
</html>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: cambia el nombre de la función no utilices *name*. y en ves de hacer una asignación estática del evento es mejor realizarla mediante javascript.

Comment: function funcion() {
         var a = document.getElementById("<?php echo $a?>").value;
         alert(a);
        } pero me sale ahora como indefinida la variable a que se debe ese error

Answer (score 1):

Cuando se ejecuta el metodo `onclick`, ese metodo se ejecuta sobre el contexto del elemento, lo que signfica que el `onclick`, interpreta que `name` *es el atributo*, no una funcion.

Si ejecutas este codigo, notaras como te prime el valor del atributo `name`:

```html
  <button onclick="alert(name)" name="hola">
   imprimir
  </button>
```

Por lo que al decirte que `name` no es una funcion es correcto porque es un atributo.

Intenta accediendo a la funcion utilizando el objeto window que es donde pertenecen todas las funciones globables. Por ejemplo:

```js
function name(){
  console.log("hola mundo");
}
```

```html
 <button onclick="window.name()" name="hola">
       imprimir
      </button>
```

O renombra tu funcion a cualquier otro nombre:

```
//..
while ($resultados=$resultado->fetch_assoc()){
    ?>

    <?php $a=$resultados['email'];?> 
    <?php $b=$resultados['idcliente'];?> 
    <ul>
        <li><a id="<?php echo $a?>" href="#" onclick="nombre();"><?php echo $a?></a></li>
    </ul>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function nombre() {
            var name = document.getElementById("<?php echo $a?>").innerHTML;
            alert(name);
        }
        </script>           
<?php }?>
```

---

Y otra cosa. Estas generando una function `name()` por cada iteracion que hace el `while`. Lo que quiere decir que si el `while` itera 5 veces, 5 funciones con el mismo nombre seran creadas y solo la ultima sera la que se tomara como referencia, no la mas cerca del evento clic.

Por ejemplo:

```
<?php

 for($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++)
 {
     ?>
    <button onclick="namef()" name="hola">
     imprimir
    </button>
      <input type="text" id="input_<?php echo $i ?>" value="<?php echo $i ?>"></input>


   <script type="text/javascript">
      function namef() {
          var f = document.getElementById("input_<?php echo $i?>").value;
          alert(f);
      }
     </script>   
<?php
 }

?>
```

Sin importar a que boton le des clic siempre imprimira 4. Intenta sacar la definicion de la funcion fuera del `while` y enviarle el id del elemento que quieres el valor por parametros a la funcion cuando se haga el evento clic asi:

```
<?php

 for($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++)
 {
     ?>
    <button onclick="namef('input_<?php echo $i ?>')" name="hola">
     imprimir
    </button>
      <input type="text" id="input_<?php echo $i ?>" value="<?php echo $i ?>"></input>

<?php
 }

?>
   <script type="text/javascript">
      function namef(id) {
          var f = document.getElementById(id).value;
          alert(f);
      }
     </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

el elemento  no contiene la propiedad value, solo los inputs tienen esa propiedad, a no ser que la asignes (que no es el caso) cambia la function name a:

```
function name(){
var name = document.getElementById("").innerHtml;
alert(name);
}
```

asi mostraras el contenido del anchor.

Answer (score 0):

Como te comenta [Einer](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/38468/einer) estás *recreando* la misma función por cada uno de los ciclos del **while**, deberías sacar fuera del *bucle* tanto la **función** como el elemento **<ul>**, y ya puestos en la línea que defines el enlace **<a>** yo le pasaría a la función como parámetro el propio elemento mediante la palabra reservada **this** en vez de pasar su '*id*':

```
<li><a id="<?php echo $a?>" href="#" onclick="name(this);"><?php echo $a?></a></li>
```

... y luego obrar en consecuencia para recojerlo en la *función 'name'* y aprovechar para realizar una simple comprobación ...

```js
function name(elemento) {
    if (elemento) { alert(elemento.innerHTML); }
}
```

... así que tienes unas cuantas opciones para implementarlo pero ¡ POR DIOS CÁMBIALE EL NOMBRE A LA FUNCIÓN ! jejjejj